# Activated Bing with Facebook only shows preview and no columns

Tags: facebook, bing

I [activated the new Bing.com experience](http://www.bing.com/search?q=movies&bnprt=spbexd&form=spbexd) [to Facebook](http://www.bing.com/explore/social) but nothing's coming up for me.

I just see "preview" label under the Bing logo and no additional columns.

> [image: bing search box]

Tried in all major browsers, no luck. Is there another way to activate it? What can restrict me from activating it (my interface is in English, location: Georgia, Tbilisi)?